# How can i restart Windows Phone 8.1 without using the power button

Tags: 8.1, buttons

The power button is unresponsive.

Is there any other way I can restart the device running Windows Phone 8.1 without using this button?

The only option I can think of right now is removing the battery and putting it back on. This is very cumbersome. Appreciate any other suggestions.

I have a Lumia 521.

Answer (score 4):

To get an onscreen button to reboot, you can change some settings:

- add a language (Settings > Language)
- switch regions or region format (Settings > Region)
- toggle navigation bar vibration (Settings > Touch)
- switch the SMS character set (Settings > Network+)
- toggle Cortana (Settings > Applications (tab) > Cortana)

I would say the third option is the most convenient.

Answer (score -1):

You can install the [Reboot Now](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=86cbd073-cbac-4297-be47-5032779eba80) app from the Store, it gives you the ability to restart the phone without using the hard button.

Comment: Note that, according to reviews in the Store, this doesn't work with WP 8.1.